# How to include SASS into CSS

Tags: html, css, sass

I am very new to `SASS` and I wonder how I would include `SASS` into `CSS`.
Taking this [example](http://callmenick.com/post/animating-css-only-hamburger-menu-icons). It says on the very bottom that with `SASS` one can edit the size of the button etc. very easy. However, how would I include the `SASS` into the project, so that the edits appear in the `CSS`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SASS need to be complied into CSS [sass-lang.com](http://sass-lang.com/install)

Try this if you don't want to install any SASS compiler.
[sassmeister.com](http://www.sassmeister.com/)

Comment: That is something I do not understand. What does it mean "to be compiled into css". How can a file containing only variables with sizes (as in the example I posted) be compiled in a css file with all the functionality?! When I copy & paste the `SASS` part of the exmple into sassmeister.com, I do not get any `css` out of it

Comment: I'm pretty sure those numbers need to be complied with other sources provide by the library. The few lines containing only variables doing nothing at all by it's self.

Comment: So I would need to install it on my machine and to something like `sass input.scss output.css`

Comment: Yes u need to get the original scss files from the github. 
https://github.com/callmenick/Animating-Hamburger-Icons/blob/adb4a70d1d977b3df3634e81738525fc6d7baa14/sass/_components.hamburger.scss

Comment: Ah now I understand. Oh man... And these I need to compile into css, right?

Comment: Exactly. Remember to get all the files. Not only the one I attached above

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me. That was very abstract... I missunderstood that a bit!

Answer (score 1):

You should first learn about [*SASS*](http://sass-lang.com/guide)

You will see that SASS is actually CSS made easy and with more features like the ability to use Variables : `$myHeight : 500px;`

In your example, he is using variable.

To inject it in your project, you need to find a way to save your SASS file in a CSS file. In the above link it is using the command

> sass --watch app/sass:public/stylesheets

But you can also do it with grunt or [gulp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sass)

Comment: So I need to compile this `SASS` file into a `CSS` file? And thats it, all the functionality (transition etc.) will be there?

Comment: Yes. After that you will see the CSS that result from your SASS and you will understand what it does exactly. Actually there is no big difference. It will replace the variable by their values and will remove the nesting by duplicating values

Comment: When I copy & paste the `SASS` from the example into here http://www.sassmeister.com/ I do not get any CSS

Comment: Acutally the sass file that you see at the end of your website **IS NOT** the full SASS file. You should get all the source file. Go on google and look for sass file example (You will quickly understand)